# gradle overwrite plugin repository from init script

Tags: gradle

How can I overwrite all plugin repositories in gradle via the init script?

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "foo" }
    }
}
```

only works for regular repositories - not for plugin repositories.
Plugins are registerd via the old `buildscript{ repositories { }}` notation

Answer (score 0):

simply adding:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript{
        repositories{
          maven { url "https://foo.com" }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://foo.com" }
    }
}
```

is the solution